# Synchronizing a counter across a network

Tags: algorithm, networking, synchronization

I have two computers that can talk to each other over a serial connection. The connection is made over a wireless network. There is a variable, changing delay in communications between the two systems. On both systems I have a counter runtime that increments by 1 every ms. They both start as soon as the applications start. Say each computer is started at different times. How can I with with the serial connection synchronize the counters so that systemA.counter will equal systemB.counter and so that both counters increment at the same time (or as close as possible).

Ideally once synchronized the counters would drift only slowly apart so that once every 3 or 4 thousand incs I could re-synchronize.

I'm looking for good resources on the topic, example algorythms, example code (c/c++), anything to point me in the right direction.

**Update**

This is a closed system, no internet. For all intents and purposes no real protocol at all besides and open serial line over the wireless link. That link at the moment is bluetooth, but I'm thinking over moving it to a ZigBee Mesh. There are currently 2 nodes, but if I have 30 nodes all running this same application I would want them all to synchronize. There is not client/server designation, just a couple of devices running the same program with a counter. I don't have access to anything like time, just this counter that increments once a millisecond and whatever algorithm I can put in place.

Once I can get this working, I would like to put in place a propositioning and mapping system, but to figure out distances between nodes, I need actuate timing synchronized on the devices.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious resource is NTP, which is documented for example at http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp.html and with links off there. Basically, this uses timestamps to adjust the frequency at which local clocks run. The protocol has been around for years and been the subject of continuous research - I can't see any pack of slides there which immediately makes it clear how it works. You might be better to see if there is already an NTP implementation available than to try and re-implement it yourself.

It appears (e.g. from searching) that there is a small industry of people working on time synchronisation algorithms, especially in the context of wireless sensor networks. One jumping-off point, apart from searches, is the survey paper at  http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.85.2012 - Time synchronization in sensor networks: A survey (2004)

Answer (score 1):

If you use this counters to order events in a system, you should look at [vector clocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_clock) or [Lamport timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport_timestamps).